# can't build wso2 emm ios agent xcode project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, wso2, wso2-iot

I imported the ios agent xcode project but when I build it I get 3 errors:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OHHTTPStubsResponse", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in ApiResponseTest.o
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_OHHTTPStubs", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in ApiResponseTest.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I think that it is something to do with adding the library, but I don't know how to do that since I'm very new to ios.

Comment: The project compiles just fine on the simulator, but when I select my ipad, the errors show up again